# Probability - Sample Space and Events Problem

Tags: probability

> A power cell consists of two subcells, each of which can provide from 0 to 5 volts, regardless of what the other subcell provides.  The power cell is functional if and only if the sum of the two voltages of the subcells is at least 6 volts.  An experiment consists of measuring and recording the voltages of the two subcells.  Let A be the event that the power cell is functional, let B be the event that two subcells have the same voltage, let C be the event that the first subcell has a strictly higher voltage than the second subcell, and let D be the event that the power cell is not functional because needs less than one additional volt to be come functional.
>
> a.  Define a sample space S for the experiment as a set of ordered pairs that makes it possible for you to express the four sets above as events.
>
> b.  Express each of the events A, B, C, and D as sets of ordered pairs that are subsets of S.
>
> c.  Express the following set in terms of A, B, C, and/or D:  $\{(x,y): x=y \text{ and } x+y \le 5 \}$.
>
> d.  Express the following events in terms of A,B,C, and/or D:  The event that the power cell is not functional and the second subcell has a strictly higher voltage than the first subcell.

Recap:  Let v1= voltage from subvcell 1 and v2=voltage from subcell 2.

A:  $v1 + v2 \ge 6$

B:  v1=v2

C:  v1 > v2

D:  $5 < v1 + v2 < 6$

I'm not sure whether I understand the question correctly.  Do the subcells only take integer values ranging 0-5 volts? If yes, then how do you have event D?  Can someone please go through and see if I'm doing this right?

Thank you in advance.

---

a.  So for this you would have 36 ordered pairs?

(0,0) ...(0,5)

$\vdots$

(5,0) ...(5,5)

---

b.

A:  The ordered pairs and the reversals, i.e.:  (a,b) and (b,a)

(1,5)

(2,4), (2,5)

(3,3), (3,4),(3,5)

(4,2),(4,3),(4,4),(4,5)

(5,1), (5,2), (5,3), (5,4), (5,5)

B:  The ordered pairs and the reversals, i.e.:  (a,b) and (b,a)

(0,0), (0,1), (0,2) (0,3),(0,4),(0,5)

(1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4),

(2,0), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3)

(3,0), (3,1), (3,2)

(4,0), (4,1)

(5,0)

C:

(1,0),

(2, {0,1})

(3, {0,1,2})

(4, {0,1,2,3})

(5, {0,1,2,3,4})

**D:  not sure how to do this if assume integer values?  Is this empty set?**

---

c.

$A=\varnothing$

B={(0,0),(1,1),(2,2)}

$C=\varnothing$

**D ??? Not sure**

---

d.  $A' \cap B' \cap C'$

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have not mistyped anything from the problem? It seems ambiguous as to whether these two random variables are discrete or continuous from the problem. If they are indeed discrete, I come to the same problem you do in defining the ordered pairs for Event D. If they are continuous, actually listing all the ordered pairs for each event would make no sense, since there would be infinitely many; unless you specified ranges for the variables, but even then it seems iffy. Can you please let us know if there is any clarification you can provide. Otherwise, I agree with your work so far

Comment: @user79790 Thanks for your comment.  I took a picture of the problem and pasted it in case I mistyped.  I think you'll find its the same.  I don't know anything more about this problem than you...

Comment: It looks to me like you have typed it correctly and I concur with @user79790 that the problem doesn't say.  Particularly part d inclines me to the view that the variables are continuous, so instead of listing ordered pairs you need a set-builder definition of the pairs in the sample space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C, you have the correct thought but $(5,\{0,1,2,3,4\})$ would not be usual notation for $\{(5,0),(5,1),(5,2),(5,3),(5,4)\}$  For D I would agree in the discrete case that it is the empty set.  The idea in c and d is to form a logical combination of A,B,C,D that represent the set described.  Your list of pairs B is correct, but you need to use union, intersection, and/or complement on A,B,C,D to express that set. The answers to c and d do not depend on whether the variables are discrete or continuous, but the answers to a and b do.

Comment: in part a, the question says define the sample space as **ordered pairs**.  Doesn't this mean it has to be discrete?  Also for part (c), is the answer they are looking for:  $B \cap A'$?  Do you agree with my part (d)?

Comment: Also, if I use set builder notation, for part (b), I would do this:  $A = \{ (v1,v2) \mid v1+v2 \ge 6\}, B= \{(v1,v2) \mid v1=v2 \}, C=\{(v1,v2) \mid v1 > v2\}, D=\{(v1, v2) \mid 5 < v1 + v2 < 6\}$.

Comment: for $0 \le v1 \le 5$ and $0 \le v2 \le 5$.

Comment: Yes, your A is a set of ordered pairs.  No, a set of ordered pairs does not need to be discrete.  I agree with your sets.